# Action button renders as full width of the card

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

When Adaptive card renders on the Web Chat Client it the actin button takes the width of the card. But the example given adaptive card designer they are not taking full width? How to fix that ?

**Here is an example how it is getting render in Web Chat**:

[image]

**But the example given in the Adaptive Samples for Chat Bot shows as following:**

[image]

**Update 1** ***************************************************************

I followed this issue https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2034#issuecomment-501818238

But somehow when I am trying to apply using adaptiveCardHostConfig, it does not show anything on the card. Here is my code:

```
   const adaptiveCardHostConfig = {
    spacing: {
    small: 3,
    'default': 8,
    medium: 20,
    large: 30,
    extraLarge: 40,
    padding: 10
    },
    separator: {
    lineThickness: 1,
    lineColor: '#EEEEEE'
    },
    supportsInteractivity: true,
    fontTypes: {
    'default': {
    fontFamily: 'Calibri, sans-serif',
    fontSizes: {
    small: 12,
    'default': 14,
    medium: 17,
    large: 21,
    extraLarge: 26
    },
    fontWeights: {
    lighter: 200,
    'default': 400,
    bolder: 600
    }
    },
    monospace: {
    fontFamily: '\'Courier New\', Courier, monospace',
    fontSizes: {
    small: 12,
    'default': 14,
    medium: 17,
    large: 21,
    extraLarge: 26
    },
    fontWeights: {
    lighter: 200,
    'default': 400,
    bolder: 600
    }
    }
    },
    containerStyles: {
    'default': {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    foregroundColors: {
    'default': {
    'default': '#000000',
    subtle: '#767676'
    },
    accent: {
    'default': '#0063B1',
    subtle: '#0063B1'
    },
    attention: {
    'default': '#FF0000',
    subtle: '#DDFF0000'
    },
    good: {
    'default': '#54a254',
    subtle: '#DD54a254'
    },
    warning: {
    'default': '#c3ab23',
    subtle: '#DDc3ab23'
    }
    }
    },
    emphasis: {
    backgroundColor: '#F0F0F0',
    foregroundColors: {
    'default': {
    'default': '#000000',
    subtle: '#767676'
    },
    accent: {
    'default': '#2E89FC',
    subtle: '#882E89FC'
    },
    attention: {
    'default': '#FF0000',
    subtle: '#DDFF0000'
    },
    good: {
    'default': '#54a254',
    subtle: '#DD54a254'
    },
    warning: {
    'default': '#c3ab23',
    subtle: '#DDc3ab23'
    }
    }
    },
    accent: {
    backgroundColor: '#C7DEF9',
    foregroundColors: {
    'default': {
    'default': '#333333',
    subtle: '#EE333333'
    },
    dark: {
    'default': '#000000',
    subtle: '#66000000'
    },
    light: {
    'default': '#FFFFFF',
    subtle: '#33000000'
    },
    accent: {
    'default': '#2E89FC',
    subtle: '#882E89FC'
    },
    attention: {
    'default': '#cc3300',
    subtle: '#DDcc3300'
    },
    good: {
    'default': '#54a254',
    subtle: '#DD54a254'
    },
    warning: {
    'default': '#e69500',
    subtle: '#DDe69500'
    }
    }
    },
    good: {
    backgroundColor: '#CCFFCC',
    foregroundColors: {
    'default': {
    'default': '#333333',
    subtle: '#EE333333'
    },
    dark: {
    'default': '#000000',
    subtle: '#66000000'
    },
    light: {
    'default': '#FFFFFF',
    subtle: '#33000000'
    },
    accent: {
    'default': '#2E89FC',
    subtle: '#882E89FC'
    },
    attention: {
    'default': '#cc3300',
    subtle: '#DDcc3300'
    },
    good: {
    'default': '#54a254',
    subtle: '#DD54a254'
    },
    warning: {
    'default': '#e69500',
    subtle: '#DDe69500'
    }
    }
    },
    attention: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFC5B2',
    foregroundColors: {
    'default': {
    'default': '#333333',
    subtle: '#EE333333'
    },
    dark: {
    'default': '#000000',
    subtle: '#66000000'
    },
    light: {
    'default': '#FFFFFF',
    subtle: '#33000000'
    },
    accent: {
    'default': '#2E89FC',
    subtle: '#882E89FC'
    },
    attention: {
    'default': '#cc3300',
    subtle: '#DDcc3300'
    },
    good: {
    'default': '#54a254',
    subtle: '#DD54a254'
    },
    warning: {
    'default': '#e69500',
    subtle: '#DDe69500'
    }
    }
    },
    warning: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFE2B2',
    foregroundColors: {
    'default': {
    'default': '#333333',
    subtle: '#EE333333'
    },
    dark: {
    'default': '#000000',
    subtle: '#66000000'
    },
    light: {
    'default': '#FFFFFF',
    subtle: '#33000000'
    },
    accent: {
    'default': '#2E89FC',
    subtle: '#882E89FC'
    },
    attention: {
    'default': '#cc3300',
    subtle: '#DDcc3300'
    },
    good: {
    'default': '#54a254',
    subtle: '#DD54a254'
    },
    warning: {
    'default': '#e69500',
    subtle: '#DDe69500'
    }
    }
    }
    },
    imageSizes: {
    small: 40,
    medium: 80,
    large: 160
    },
    actions: {
    maxActions: 100,
    spacing: 'default',
    buttonSpacing: 8,
    showCard: {
    actionMode: 'inline',
    inlineTopMargin: 8
    },
    actionsOrientation: 'vertical',
    actionAlignment: 'stretch'
    },
    adaptiveCard: {
    allowCustomStyle: false
    },
    imageSet: {
    imageSize: 'medium',
    maxImageHeight: 100
    },
    factSet: {
    title: {
    color: 'default',
    size: 'default',
    isSubtle: false,
    weight: 'bolder',
    wrap: true,
    maxWidth: 150
    },
    value: {
    color: 'default',
    size: 'default',
    isSubtle: false,
    weight: 'default',
    wrap: true
    },
    spacing: 8
    }
    };

    window.ReactDOM.render(
    <ReactWebChat directLine={ window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: "xxxxx" })}
                  styleSet={ styleSet }
                  store={ store }
                  adaptiveCardHostConfig={ adaptiveCardHostConfig } />,
    document.getElementById('webchat'));
    document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
    })().catch(err => console.error(err));
```

It just shows a blank adaptive card in chat window:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1964) on GitHub.

Comment: Change your web chat implementation and control the visual behaviour that way.

Comment: Adaptive Cards Host Config should be customizable.  I've filed an issue on the GitHub repo for this: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2034

Comment: @tdurnford: I have updated my problem statement after reading your comment in Github, but somehow its not working when used with ReactWebChat.

Comment: What version of Web Chat are you using?

Comment: @Corina: This is what I am using  https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js

Comment: @Dadwals thanks for the info, this will be fixed in the next release of Web Chat

Answer (score 0):

The fix will be released soon for this. Please check the following github issue:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2102